# Angular sui-select options not updating when options model changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, semantic-ui, ngmodel

I'm using the Angular package for Semantic UI https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/getting-started

I have a searchable, dropdown select like so:

```
<sui-select class="selection" [options]="myOptionsModel" [isSearchable]="true" #questionSearch>
  <sui-select-option *ngFor="let option of questionSearch.filteredOptions" [value]="option"></sui-select-option>
</sui-select>
```

Whenever I update `myOptionsModel`, the options in the select don't update accordingly..(i.e. if I add or remove an item, the change doesn't get reflected)

Here's how I'm updating `myOptionsModel`:
Upon a click event from some button, this function is called:

```
addOption(name: string, id: number) {
  this.myOptionsModel.push({name: name, id: id})
}
```

I've tried multiple approaches like using `optionsLookUp` but no luck.. Can you help?

Comment: Just in case anyone (like me) visits this from a `ngx-semantic` background: `[options]` etc are no longer valid, use `[suiOptions]` etc as appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update an **async** object with **sync** logic.

**myOptionsModel** should be an **observable**
Then you HTML template can bind to Its changes

*TS file*

```
myOptionsModel$: BehaviorSubject<MyObjectType[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

addOption(name: string, id: number) {
    const updatedModel = this.myOptionsModel$.value.concat([{id, name}])
    this.myOptionsModel$.next(updatedModel)
  }
```

*HTML file*

```
[options]="myOptionsModel$ | async"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Can you please show me how I'd update `myOptionsModel` now that it's an Observable?

Comment: Sure, update the question with how are you updating today, and I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question. The add logic is pretty rudimentary.

Comment: hi.. I have a follow up question.. What if I want to bind the selected choice to a variable? The normal `[(ngModel)]` binding doesn't seem to work anymore..

Comment: Is your selected choice variable a Observable?